# laravel many to many relationship with custom query

Tags: laravel

I have Two table Products and Props With Many to Many Relationship.
Every Product have some props and Every prop is for some Products.
In search filter i need only get products with selected props.
how can i do this?

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('title');
    ....
    $table->timestamps();
});
Schema::create('props', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('title');
    ....
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('product_prop', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('prop_id');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->foreign('product_id')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('products')
          ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('prop_id')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('props')
          ->onDelete('cascade');
});

products: 
id=> 1, title=> p1
id=> 2, title=> p2
id=> 3, title=> p3
id=> 4, title=> p4
id=> 5, title=> p5
props:
id=> 1, title=> p1
id=> 2, title=> p2
id=> 3, title=> p3
id=> 4, title=> p4
id=> 5, title=> p5

product 1 has prop 1 and 2
product 3 has prop 2 and 4
product 4 has prop 5

$selectedProps = [1,5]
```

so i need to get product 1 and 4!
but i don't know how to get.

Comment: Show your code what you have done?

Comment: can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code,
before that I assume,
you have `Products` Model and `Props` Model.

in your `Product` Model

```
public function props(){
   return $this->hasMany('Props');
}
```

and in your `Props` Model

```
public function product(){
   return $this->belongsToMany('Product');
}
```

Now the builder to get  products for the selected props.

```
Props::with('product')->whereHas('product')->where('id', $selectedPropsId)->get();
```

Note: My answer is based on your question, and sorry, your questions didn't have more information.

Comment: if you want multiple props selected, then use `Props::with('product')->whereHas('product')->whereId('id', $selectedPropsId)->get();` here `$selectedPropsId` is an array of selected props ids

Comment: please mark this answer as correct , and upvote. this will help others also. 
Thank you

Comment: I paid a little more attention and realized that this is not what I need.
I need the products that has the selected props.